# iOS Change every cell colour (section + row)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I would like to change cell color in every cell (4 colours % 4) :

**1. Section 1**

Cell 1 : RED

Cell 2 : BLUE

**2. Section 2**

Cell 3 : BLACK

**3. Section 3**

Cell 4 : WHITE

**4. Section 4**

Cell 5 : RED

Cell 6 : BLUE

Cell 7 : BLACK
...

How can I achieve this ?

I know how to change color in `cellForRow` :         `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:119.0/255.0 green:221.0/255 blue:167.0/255 alpha:1.0f];`

Comment: are there more than 7 cells, or is that a set amount?

Comment: @BJHStudios equal, or more or less than 7 cells 

Comment: What I understood from the question description is that you want the background colours in a sequence i.e. RED, BLUE, BLACK, WHITE and so on regardless of the section, right? And which language are you using?

Comment: @Adeel Objective-C  yeah you're right

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have an array of arrays that stores your section and row data. I would create a function that takes a section and row number as arguments and returns a position that ignores the section:

```
- (Int) getPosition:(Int) section rowNumber:(Int) row {
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < section; i++) {
        position += DataArray[i].count;
    }
   return position + row;
}
```

This would add up all the counts in previous sections, then add the row in the current section, to give you a new number to use for the coloring. Then to call it, write this in your cellForRow method:

```
newIndex = [self getPosition:indexPath.section rowNumber:indexPath.row]
```

If you use this number to determine the colors, it'll be colored correctly.

Comment: Don't succeed to implement in Objective-C

Comment: I edited my response to my best attempt at objective-c. You would put this function in your tableViewController class, then call it from your cellForRowAt method to get an absolute index regardless of the section.

Comment: Ok, so after, what I've to call in cellForRow ? 

Comment: Just edited my answer. I work primarily with Swift, so the syntax might be a little off.

Comment: Thanks Adam ! See my answer, I think that's what you explain to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a switch case statment to resolve this problem

create a function to return to you a `UIColor` and as a paramter of this method, send a number from 0 to 3

```
-(UIColor *)colorForCell:(NSInteger)index {
    switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    return RED
                    break;
                case 1:
                    return BLUE
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return BLACK
                    break;
                case 3:
                    return WHITE
                    break;

                default:
                    return RED
                    break;
            } 
}
```

and than just do `cellForRow :  cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorForCell:index]`

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried [self colorForCell:indexPath.row] --> need to give NSUInteger

Answer (score 0):

Found solution :

```
NSInteger rowNumber = 0;
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
    rowNumber += [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}

rowNumber += indexPath.row;
switch (rowNumber % 4) {
    case 0:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        break;
    case 3:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to select one of the four colours mentioned in the question in a sequence based on the index/position of the cell irrespective of the section so this would do for you.

```
- (UIColor *)colorForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UIColor *cellColor;
NSInteger index = 0;

for (NSInteger i=0; 1<indexPath.section; i++) {

    index += [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}

index += indexPath.row;

switch (index % 4) {

    case 0:
        cellColor = [UIColor redColor];
        break;

    case 1:
        cellColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;

    case 2:
        cellColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        break;

    case 3:
        cellColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

return cellColor;
}
```

Call this method in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and pass the `indexPath` as parameter.